# Why can't I change the weights of subdivided bones?

Tags: bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I have character with ready armature. I want to make forearm twist & for this need to subdivide bone. When I do this, I can't change weights for these bones.

Maybe there is some way for weights to be automatically distributed when bones are subdivided? Or at least how to fix weights in this case?

I tried Assign automatic from bones, Normalize, Normalize all, I even removed all weights from this bone, but result still remained the same:

[image]

Comment: could you please share this part of your mesh + armature? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yes, of course. Here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Nb5oARvx" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Nb5oARvx/)

Comment: I don't know why you say that you can't change the weight for these bones, it looks like you can. Also, why don't you use a unique bone for the forearm and choose B-bone and segment it? Wouldn't it make the twist simpler?

Comment: I did a little wrong. I gave original model. Here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=yjB2v6Qs" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/yjB2v6Qs/). Here I subdivided forearm bone & I tried to change weights, but it didn't work out.
If segmenting B-Bone, it's the same as subdivide, isn't it?

Comment: it's not the same as subdividing, maybe you should take a look

Comment: And how to use B-Bones to rotate forearm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some of the vertices of the biceps are influenced by several bones, if you select one vertex of this zone and open the *N* panel (on the right of your 3D View) > *Item* tab > *Vertex Weights*, you'll see a series of vertex groups that the vertex should not be part of.

Also, if you select your armature and go in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Skeleton > Layers*, you have a lot of hidden bones that have their *Deform* option activated and that will influence this part of the body.

For example it looks like the wrist is the parent of some upper arm bones, therefore when you rotate the wrist it deforms the upper arm mesh. It makes no sense, you should probably correct these bones relationships. This correction should fix the problem.

[image]

But if you want to entirely redo the weight painting you can select the part of the mesh you want to rework, go in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Vertex Groups* and on the left of the Vertex Groups list, click on the down arrow icon and choose *Remove From All*, which will de-assign these vertices from all groups.

Now you can work in *Weight Paint* mode and give to this part the influence that each bone is supposed to have.

Instead of subdividing your forearm, you could choose to display your bones as *B-bones* instead of *Stick* (*Properties panel > Object Data > Display As*). Then choose the bone you want to segment and in the *Properties panel > Bone > Bendy Bones*, choose the amount of *Segments* you want for this bone. Then give it a constraint *Copy Rotation* that you put above the *IK Constraint*, and choose the hand as *Target*, *Space > Pose Space / Pose Space*. The bone flexibility is set in the *Properties panel > Bone > Bendy Bones > Easing*.

[image]

Comment: So, it means that other bones didn't allow to change weights. And as I understood, if click Remove from all, then after that need to redraw all weights on all along arm again, right? This is certainly not fun, but at least I found out the cause of this problem. Thank you so much for explaining.
By the way, maybe there's a way to copy weight from those bones to weight of main bones?

Comment: I've edited to show you where your problem comes from, the wrist is parent of hidden bones that are located in the upper arm, it makes no sense, these bones should logically be parented to the upper arm bone, it may fix your problem.

Comment: I tried to do as you said with B-Bones, but that doesn't work. When I rotate Hand bone, entire Forearm bone just repeats this rotation. And it doesn't react to Easing at all. More precisely, mesh doesn't respond to any changes in B-Bones.

Comment: Ok so I've given a try and B-Bone should work fine but hard to dive into this new topic here, try to fix your current problem with the answer I gave, maybe try B-Bones on a brand new file to test it  ;)

Comment: I don't quite understood. Create new .blend file & move model there? In any case, I tried several times to do as you wrote, but nothing came of it.

Comment: As I said it's a completely different topic, so it would be tedious to discuss here, my initial answer should fix your current problem, your problem was these hidden bones that should not be controlled by the wrist bone

Comment: I understood. In any case, thank you for help with weights.